# Using multiple jQuery UI sortables with overlapping lists

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to write a page that will allow users to drag items between two lists, and reorder them.

I have a main list on the left, and a "bucket" list on the right. The idea is to let users place items in the bucket as a holding area while they move around the page (the main list can get quite long, so it's useful to let them place items in the bucket while they scroll somewhere else to drop them)

To accomplish this, I've positioned the "bucket" at a fixed location on the page so that it scrolls with the user. Because of different browser sizes, it's possible for the "bucket" to overlap with the main list. When this happens, and an item is dragged from the main list to the bucket, the bucket will not receive the item if the mouse cursor is in the overlapping area between the main list and the bucket.

**To reproduce the problem:**

Here is some HTML to reproduce the problem (it simulates the situation where the bucket is floating on top of the main list):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
      ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 1px solid #777; }
      li { margin-bottom: 2px; background-color: #EEE; border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB; width: 300px; height: 40px; }
      #main-list { z-index: -1; width: 300px; }
      #bucket { width: 202px;  position: fixed; top: 20px; left: 250px; border: 3px solid #CCC; }
      #bucket-list { z-index: 999; min-height: 300px; width: 200px; }
      #bucket-list li { width: 200px; }
      .placeholder { background-color: #28D; }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#main-list, #bucket-list" ).sortable({
                scroll: false,
                connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
                placeholder: "placeholder",
                tolerance: "pointer"
            }).disableSelection();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="main-list" class="connectedSortable">
        <li>Foo1</li>
        <li>Foo2</li>
        <li>Foo3</li>
        <li>Foo4</li>
        <li>Foo5</li>
        <li>Foo6</li>
        <li>Foo7</li>
        <li>Foo8</li>
        <li>Foo9</li>
        <li>Foo10</li>
        <li>Foo11</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="bucket">
        <ul id="bucket-list" class="connectedSortable">
            <li>Bar1</li>
            <li>Bar2</li>
            <li>Bar3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Render the HTML in a browser, and click and drag item "Foo6" into the "Bar" list (the bucket). Drag the item slowly, into the side of the bucket, and notice that the draggable does not get recognized by the bucket until your cursor crosses the boundary where the two lists overlap.

**The question:**

In a situation where two jQueryUI sortables overlap, I would like the sortable that is visually on top to receive the draggable when a draggable is placed on it, instead of the sortable that is visually beneath.
How can I do this?

Thanks!